# Timeout em execução de tarefa Asynctask

Tags: java, android

Como faço para limitar o tempo de execução de uma `Asynctask` e retornar um aviso quando o limite for atingido ?

O método busca um json de um webservice, mas o mesmo poderá estar fora do ar, e quando isso acontece o app fica tentando por muito tempo até dar o erro.

```
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

    StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        URL url = new URL("endereco.com/dados.php");
        URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            content.append(line + "\n");
        }
        bufferedReader.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Acredito que seria o caso de setar um timeout no momento da abertura da conexão com o webservice

Comment: @Henrique seria aqui que seto esse timeout `URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();` ?

Comment: Isso, reformule a pergunta e acrescente o código referente a conexão, que tento formular uma resposta.

Comment: Pergunta alterada !

Comment: Seria isso: `urlConnection.setConnectTimeout()` né

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adicione um `timeout` para a conexão com seu webservice:

```
protected String doInBackground(Void...params) {

    StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        URL url = new URL("endereco.com/dados.php");
        URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
        urlConnection.setReadTimeout(5000);

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            content.append(line + "\n");
        }
        bufferedReader.close();

    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

- [`setReadTimeout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setReadTimeout(int)) define o tempo limite para leitura.
- [`setConnectTimeout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setConnectTimeout(int)) define o tempo limite para uma tentativa de conexão.

Para ambos os métodos, informe o valor em milissegundo, se ocorrer o `timeout`, pode capturar o evento utilizando a exceção [`SocketTimeoutException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/net/SocketTimeoutException.html)

Comment: Henrique, qualquer um dos 2 se caso derem o tempo limite, eles caem em Exception correto !? Em vista ele acusa o mesmo erro `org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of` teria tratativa para separar qual o real motivo ?

Comment: Isso, ambos iram cair em `Exception`. Sobre esse `JSONException`, é outro problema em algum outro ponto.